# How to change Y axis scaling limit in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, yaxis

## I am trying to draw a secondary axis plot of wind speed and wind direction.

```
p \<- ggplot(df, aes(x = date))
p \<- p + geom_line(aes(y = wd, colour = "wind direction"))
p \<- p + geom_line(aes(y = ws\*25, colour = "wind speed"))


p \<- p + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(\~./25, name = "wind spped (ms )"))


p \<- p + scale_colour_manual(values = c("#e377c2", "#7f7f7f"))
p \<- p + labs(y = "wind direction (°)")
p \<- p + theme(text = element_text(size = 12)) + xlab("") + theme_light () +
theme(legend.position = "null") + theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())
p
```

I can able to produce the figure. However, I want to edit the scale of the primary axis as (0, 90 ,180, 270, 360). When I am adding ylim =c(0, 90, 180, 270, 360) in the primary axis, I the secondary axis is not showing up. Let me know how to slove this.

Comment: Are the \'s in your code intended?

Comment: Can you include some sample data so we can run the code?

Answer (score 0):

From the help for `ylim`:

> Arguments ...  For xlim() and ylim(): **Two** numeric values, specifying
> the left/lower limit and the right/upper limit of the scale. If the
> larger value is given first, the scale will be reversed. You can leave
> one value as NA if you want to compute the corresponding limit from
> the range of the data.

`ylim`, equivalent to `scale_y_continuous(limits = ....)` expects a vector with two elements, the min and max. You might want `breaks` instead if you are defining the y axis tick/grid/label levels.

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date("2023-01-01") + 30 * (0:3),
                 wd = 360*runif(4),
                 ws = 15*runif(4))

ggplot(df, aes(x = date, wd)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = "wind direction")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = ws*25, colour = "wind speed")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 90 * (0:4),
                     limits = c(0, 360),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./25, name = "wind speed (ms )"))
```

[image]